# "No symbol has been loaded for this document" when debug asp.net mvc framework source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

I am trying to debug asp.net mvc source code. Here are the steps I took:

1. I set up a bare-bone asp.net mvc application (version 5.2.4) by using the template offered by Visual Studio 2017.
2. I downloaded asp.net mvc source code from [offcial github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack), and according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application), MvcHandler will be hit in the code path so I put a breakpoint in its processRequest() method.
3. I follow the instruction from the microsoft reference web [(there is a link on the main page)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib,namespaces) about how to set up VS and I use "https://referencesource.microsoft.com" as symbol server.
4. During debugging, I also make sure "System.Web.Mvc.dll" is loaded (dll for MvcHandler).

I think I get both source code and pdb, but I still get error: "no symbol has been loaded for this document". I want to know what other steps I can take to solve this.

Some other posts I read:

[(1) can't debug asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018521/source-information-is-missing-from-the-debug-information-for-this-module-when)

[(2) same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728189/source-information-missing-from-the-debug-information-for-this-module-pdb-succ)

Comment: You can try `Cleaning` your solution or try this: Debug=>Options=>General => Remove the check mark for "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: @RahulSharma I tried both but no luck :(

Comment: There could many reasons why you are getting this error. I believe this link would help you in your problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97445/vs2017-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no.html

Comment: Your 1st link in point #3 doesn't go to where you intended it to, I think.

Comment: @IanKemp I updated the description, there is a link near the top of that page. According to "(2) same error message", I suspect the code is undebuggable (the Zi parameter), but can't know for sure

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need for you to download the MVC 5 source code, the whole point of symbols and source servers is to fetch those source files for you as needed while debugging.

> I use "https://referencesource.microsoft.com" as symbol server

That's likely your problem - Reference Source is *only* for the .NET Framework. In order to get MVC 5 symbols and source files, you need to add a different symbol server, such as SymbolSource - see http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Wiki/Using.

You should also be aware that a lot of the information around debugging with symbols is outdated. In particular, in VS 2017 and later, there is a new option under Tools > Options > Debugging > General called "Use managed compatibility mode", which should be **unchecked**.

If all else fails, since you already have the MVC source on your machine, simply point your solution at - either by removing the MVC DLL references and including and referencing the relevant projects in your solution, or by replacing the MVC DLL references with references to your own locally-compiled DLLs. This is a lot more pain and effort than using symbol servers, but it's also 100% reliable.

For troubleshooting purposes, the Modules window (Debug > Windows > Modules when debugging) is invaluable; it will show you what DLLs were loaded by your project, what PDBs were loaded for them and where from, and if a PDB wasn't loaded it will tell you why. You can also manually force a PDB to be loaded via right-clicking a particular DLL and browsing to its location.

See also: [Debugging Asp.net MVC 5.2.3 source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903669/debugging-asp-net-mvc-5-2-3-source-code)

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I tried your suggestion but still get the same error message. But building the code locally seems promising. I avoided it before because it's more work but seems like it's my only choice left....

Comment: unfortunately, building locally also doesn't work. Because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212035/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-st, which is annoying. Someone else also share my frustration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337092/cannot-step-into-mvc4-methods

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
Instead of using Asp.net Mvc 5.2.4, I downloaded the latest Mvc package here: https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetwebstack-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
and that does the trick for me (Everything else I did stay the same).

So if one version doesn't work for you, try a different version!